# I have been offered 10% of the profit, how do I know if this is the right percentage?

Tags: contracts, payment-terms, pay-rate, price

I have been offered to develop a web application from scratch and have been offered 10% of the pie, if and when the project becomes profitable.

I'm not sure if 10% is right, they say I will be the fifth partner.

Is 10% about right in such situations? Where a technical guy develops from scratch? Can somebody point to any metrics I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being duped.

You're doing 100% of the work for the POTENTIAL of 10% of the profits.

- How will the site be marketed?
- How much money will be spent on   marketing?
- *Whose* money will be spent on marketing?
- What *is* the target market?
- How much will the services be sold for?
- Who collects and distributes the money?
- How long between the time a customer pays and the time you get your 10%???
- Who OWNS the software?
- Who's going to run and control the web server?
- Who will be the owner-of-record for the site?
- Can you prevent your business partners from running off with your work?
- What is the form of the organization? (corporation, LLC, partnership, etc)
- *How* will it be documented that you are a partner?
- What is the work background of all the partners?  How does each one's experience directly benefit the partnership?
- How much work is everyone else expected to do?

If you haven't answered all of these questions, don't do a shred of work until you can.  If you go asking these questions and there's any hesitation by your partners, RUN LIKE HELL.  Leave it alone.